# how to use a comma to separate two strings in a variable in python

Tags: python, string

I am a beginner to python and am working on python 3.6.5 ,  I was trying to create a Chatbot but I don't understand how to use a comma to separate the two strings(red and Red) because the shell says that it is an invalid syntax(the comma is highlighted but nothing else). What have I done wrong?:

```
colour=input("What is  your favourite colour? ")  
if colour=="red", "Red":  
    print("Red is my favourite colour as well")
```

note:I know this question is very similar to others on the forum but considering I am only a beginner (I literally started learning python on friday) the answers for the other question were a bit confusing because they had different code,so I asked this question using what I am learning.

Comment: What do you want this to mean: `if colour=="red", "Red"`?

Comment: @theausome errr... no... `and` is pretty much what you don't want when checking the same variable against multiple values :)

Comment: @JonClements yeah I see that now.

Comment: Why not use `colour.lower()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in`

```
colour= input("What is  your favourite colour? ")  
if colour in ("red", "Red"):  
    print("Red is my favourite colour as well")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You could you use if colour in ['red', 'Red', 'RED', 'ReD'] as mentionned earlier, or you could just sanitize the input:

```
colour= input("What is  your favourite colour? ")
if colour.lower() == "red":
    print("Red is my favourite colour as well")
```